# PhpmyAdmin designer does not show relation between DB table

Tags: phpmyadmin

As title suggest, when i click on "designer" button in PhpmyAdmin, I only see table with no connection each to other. Why? there's something out of sets?
How can I remedy?

Comment: Isn't this because your tables isn't `INNODB`, which are the only table type  that natively supports relationships? If you tables are `MyISAM` you can try to convert them to `INNODB`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help..My tables are all INNODB..

Comment: This link might be useful: http://www.w3expert.com/2008/03/how-to-enable-view-feature-in.html

Comment: when i clicked the Go button, it has been reported the follower message, what does it mean?

Comment: -- SQL Commands to set up the pmadb as described in the documentation.

Comment: -- 
-- This file is meant for use with MySQL 5 and above!
-- 
-- This script expects the user pma to already be existing. If we would put a
-- line here to create him too many users might just use this script and end
-- up with having the same password for the controluser.
--                                                     
-- This user "pma" must be defined in config.inc.php (controluser/controlpass)                         
--                                                  
-- Please don't forget to set up the tablenames in config.inc.php                                 
--

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?